# Как правильно скрыть файлы от пользователя

Tags: ios, objective-c, безопасность, apple, хранение-данных

Как хранить файлы, загружаемые с сервера (и весом в среднем в пару гигов), в закрытую от юзера, который умеет пользоваться файловым менеджером типа ifunbox?

Ситуация примерно такая: есть платный контент от компании, в данном случае фильмы, продают они показы. Приложение позволяет купить определенное число показов, загрузить фильм на ipad и просматривать внутри приложения.
После определенного количества просмотров фильм удаляется. Компания хочет, чтобы фильмы, которые она предоставляет, не смог вытащить хотя бы обычный юзер.

Comment: Если пользователь пользуется файл-менеджером, то он _хочет_ видеть все файлы. Вы не должны пытаться делать что-то враждебное к вашему пользователю.

Comment: вам надо чтоб он вообще не видел файлы, или видел но не мог посмотреть их содержимое?

Comment: Не мог просмотреть - уже было бы хорошо

Comment: посмотрите любую encryption библиотеку. Если надо, ключ спрячьте в Keychain

Comment: раз это фильмы - сделайте кастомный кодек или используйте обычный drm, который как раз для этого и придуман, но никому не нужен:)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko а на производительности сильно скажется? Не будет ли задержка слишком долгой, если каждый фильм нужно будет расшифровать перед просмотром?

Comment: Я не посмотрел, что речь про фильмы. Тогда DRM (digital rights management) ваш выбор. посмотрите fairplay и widevine.

Comment: @KoVadim позвольте с вами не согласиться - drm сейчас набирает обороты.

Comment: А если хотите фильмы хранить на устройстве, тогда наверно логичнее всего хранить их в формате HLS, кусками по 6-10 секунд и пока играется один расшифровывать и подготавливать следующий.

Comment: В ios10 добавили возможность хранить hls файлы локально и векриптить их используя локальные ключи

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko как-нибудь посмотрю, спасибо, как раз собирались сделать обновление шифрования

Answer (score 0):

Просто поменяйте местами небольшой участок кода в начале файла (или не только в начале) - достаточно несколько байт (1 2 3 4 5 6 -> 1 4 5 2 3 6)

Добавить и удалить их займет миллисекунды, обычный пользователь воспроизвести файлы не сможет. Профессионал конечно сможет исправить, но это будет просто не оправдано по цене (особенно если участки в файлах будут разные).

Зато вам не придется тратить процессорное время на шифровку/дешифровку и вообще возится с шифрованием.